# Kubernetes fanout ingress using Voyager seems to be not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have a working Kubernetes gossip-based cluster deployed on AWS using Kops.
I have been studying ingress using both of these.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

https://github.com/appscode/voyager

I followed the steps using both on seperate clusters.
I am using without RBAC for now.
So far things have worked better using `ingress-nginx`.
Am expecting more from voyager based on what I read on the site.

After setup I ran this command 
kubectl `create -f my-ingress.yml`
with following content in the yml file

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress
      annotations:
        ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    spec:
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /web
            backend:
              serviceName: service2
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service2
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /exp
            backend:
              serviceName: service1
              servicePort: 8080
```

When using voyager unlike with ingress-nginx I cannot see the load balancer external url in output of "kubectl describe ing <ingressname>
But thats ok.
I figured out how to reach it. Voyager creates a service for this load balancer.
I reached the external endpoint url from that service.

**Issue** is that *in voyager unlike with ingress-nginx I am only able to access what is mapped under root i.e. / and not what is mapped under /web or /exp.*

Please suggest.

### R

Tried codefx's suggestion.
Problem is still there in voyager. I tried moving the paths up and down. The root i.e. / still works. But there is basically a a variation of one of these 2 error messages for the other 2 paths /web and /exp.

**Variation 1**

```
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1>
<p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p>
<div id='created'>Sun Oct 22 20:32:20 UTC 2017</div>
<div>There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).</div>
<div>No message available</div>
</body></html>
```

**Variation 2**

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.5</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Will try again tomorrow. Codefx, I hope you also read my comments below

Comment: From https://github.com/appscode/voyager/blob/master/docs/user-guide/ingress/ingress-annotations.md#voyager-annotations it looks like voyager does not currently support ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: "Simple fanout" is not working with voyager.It would work with "Name based virtual hosting" . That may not be compatible with my  my gossip based (not DNS) cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

- Voyager does not support rewrite-target annotation currently. You can achieve the same functionality using the `rewriteRule` option. But this will require using Voyager's CRD instead of standard ingress. Without path rewrite nginx keeps returning 404. This is tracked here: https://github.com/appscode/voyager/issues/657
- In Voyager, the order of rules and paths are important as Voyager will use them in the order provided by user, instead of automatically reordering them. So, if you move the `/` path to the last, it should do what you expect.

Below is a fully working example that I tested:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
kubectl expose deployment nginx --name=web --port=80 --target-port=80

kubectl run test-server --image=appscode/test-server:1.1
kubectl expose deployment test-server --name=exp --port=80 --target-port=8080

kubectl run echoserver --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4
kubectl expose deployment echoserver --name=rest --port=80 --target-port=8080
```

Ingress YAML using Voyager CRD (note the apiVersion):

```
apiVersion: voyager.appscode.com/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-demo
  annotations:
    ingress.appscode.com/type: NodePort
    ingress.appscode.com/force-service-port: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /web
        backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 80
          rewriteRules:
          - '^([^\ ]*\ /)web(.*)   \1\2'
      - path: /exp
        backend:
          serviceName: exp
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: rest
          servicePort: 80
```

To use the CRD with kubectl, you need to use full resource name:

`kubectl describe ingress.voyager.appscode.com  fanout-demo`

Please try it. It should solve your issue.

Edit:
- rewrite-target annotations are currently supported by Voyager. (Feb, 2018)

Comment: I had to edit the question to make sure I added as much information I could in context of your reply. But problem is still there

Comment: There is some improvement. I did a fresh build of my kubernetes cluster and used a fresh clone of voyager. Now only /web is not working. Other 2 paths root i.e / and /exp are working. Please see this google doc for all the details. Let me know if you need more information.  I keep my cluster down when not using it. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WVj8YRnUxPy1RG0B_jJDxeNYHuu6So5NrfdtL8prNdo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Will check and get back